# Вывод элемента из String[] массива по его индексу

Tags: java, android, массивы, строки

У меня есть два массива

```
String[] pazmassiv = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
String[] dvamassiv = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

Есть `spinner` и он гребет данные из `razmassiv`а

Получаю числа из `spinner`а так:

```
String FromSpinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Вставляю так:

```
toastText.setText(FromSpinner + "текст");
```

Мне нужно объединить эти два массива параллельно, но выводить раздельно. 
Т.е. выбираю я `1` с индексом `0` в массиве.. И! из второго `dvamassiv` массива, мне выводит элемент с темже индексом в допустим:

```
EditText.setText(FromDvamassiv);
```

Извиняюсь если так сложно объснил:)
Варианты с:

```
String result = razmassiv[0].concat(" + ").concat(dvamassiv[0]);
```

..работают!, но мне же нужно подставлять число из `spinner`а

Comment: Учиться вы должны в школе и университете. Тут вам могут что-то подсказать, но не заниматься вашим образованием.

Comment: Ну я имел ввиду по этой теме, куда копать может подкажете или сразу ответ дадите. Всё равно спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```
int ind = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

для получения индекса выбраного элемента, потом

```
String result = razmassiv[ind].concat(" + ").concat(dvamassiv[ind]);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Не догадался до int ind = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

Comment: @Сергей, если помог, то можете смело отблагодарить галочкой возле ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно на спинер поставить слушатель **OnItemSelectedListener**

```
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 

    someEditText.setText(razmassiv[position].concat(" + ").concat(dvamassiv[position]););

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: К сожалению, такой вариант мне не подходит. Я сделал как выше ответили. Но ваш вариант запишу к себе в заметки :)